# How to apply binary diff produced by fc to a file?

Tags: windows, diff, patch

How can one apply diff file produced by `fc /b` command on Windows to update some file in a simplest way possible; i.e. without buying anything or downloading some large/questionable software?

The diff file looks something like this:

```
myold.fil mynew.fil
0000100A: 00 10
0000100B: 00 30
```

What I need is to produce the mynew.fil from myold.fil.

Comment: Related StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15835226/94928

Answer (score 1):

I will be using [this PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/Dither/3cb04e90636e85ae7361) for now.

> ```
> # Script for applying fc /b or .dif kind of binary diffs to files.
> # Run using this command: 
> #   powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File "fc2bin.ps1"
> # Difference file should have the following format:
>
> #    Description line
> #
> #    myold.fil
> #    0000100A: 00 10
> #    0000100B: 00 30
> ```