# Sysinternals Handle prints question marks "?" instead of non ASCII symbols

Tags: windows, sysinternals

For files that contain non ASCII symbols, The [Sysinternals Handle utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) prints the file names with `?`. A similar problem is also reported in the following places:

- [Handle encoding problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/162624/handle-encoding-problem.html)
- [Russian language in Handle.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/278960/russian-language-in-handle-exe)
- [Question about Handle.exe in SysInternals](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/question-about-handleexe-in-sysinternals/1ba271c3-a839-4b85-aada-1fb14f507eda)

### Reproduction scenario

- Open a file `C:\test\fileфайлファイル文件.pdf` in Adobe Acrobat Reader just to lock it.
- Executing the following command in `cmd.exe` results in the file name being printed as `C:\test\file??????????.pdf`:

```
C:\> handle64 -nobanner C:\test\fileфайлファイル文件.pdf
Acrobat.exe        pid: 10616  type: File           440: C:\test\file??????????.pdf
```

- The same occurs if I redirect the output to a file by using the command `handle64 -nobanner C:\test\fileфайлファイル文件.pdf > 1.txt`. The file content will be the same as in a console. Opening the file in a HEX editor shows that `?` signs are actual question marks with the code `x3F`. Therefore, I assume that it is not a problem with the encoding on my machine.

### Question

How can it be fixed or worked around?

### Best workaround at the moment.

Binary patch from [@NewcomerAl's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1796185/1182474) fixes this issue. The patched binary can be downloaded from the [Sysinternals-console-utils-with-Unicode-support](https://github.com/PolarGoose/Sysinternals-console-utils-with-Unicode-support) GitHub repository.

Comment: Try to enter the command `chcp 65001` to use UTF8 encoding. Does that help?

Comment: No, I have tried it, it didn't help. The result is the same.

Comment: It's likely a problem with Handle - you might signal the author.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to workaround this issue by applying the following binary patch to [HANDLE64.EXE V5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) that injects `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT)` at the beginning of the `main` function. This function makes Handle tool print its output in UTF8 format that supports non ASCII symbols.

#### Patch

```
# Description
# injects `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT)` at the beginning of the `main` function. Only works for "HANDLE64.EXE v5.0"
handle64.exe
00008510: 48 E9
00008511: 33 FF
00008512: C4 DF
00008513: 48 02
00008514: 89 00
00036514: 00 50
00036515: 00 51
00036516: 00 52
00036517: 00 41
00036518: 00 50
00036519: 00 41
0003651A: 00 51
0003651B: 00 48
0003651C: 00 83
0003651D: 00 EC
0003651E: 00 30
0003651F: 00 BA
00036522: 00 04
00036524: 00 B9
00036525: 00 01
00036529: 00 E8
0003652A: 00 7A
0003652B: 00 FD
0003652C: 00 FD
0003652D: 00 FF
0003652E: 00 48
0003652F: 00 83
00036530: 00 C4
00036531: 00 30
00036532: 00 41
00036533: 00 59
00036534: 00 41
00036535: 00 58
00036536: 00 5A
00036537: 00 59
00036538: 00 58
00036539: 00 48
0003653A: 00 33
0003653B: 00 C4
0003653C: 00 48
0003653D: 00 89
0003653E: 00 84
0003653F: 00 24
00036540: 00 50
00036541: 00 01
00036544: 00 E9
00036545: 00 D2
00036546: 00 1F
00036547: 00 FD
00036548: 00 FF
```

#### How to apply

1. Save the abovementioned patch into a file `patch.txt` and place it next to the `handle64.exe` executable.
2. Download a powershell script from this [answer by @DitherSky](https://superuser.com/a/799355/1182474) and place the script next to the `handle64.exe` executable.
3. Create a batch script file `runme.cmd` with commands below and place it next to the `handle64.exe` executable:

```
@cd /d "%~dp0"
@powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File fc2bin.ps1 -Apply patch.txt
@pause
```

4. Run the batch script `runme.cmd` to apply fix to the `handle64.exe` executable.

Comment: Hello, you really should state what the patch is exactly changing.

Comment: And how to apply it and where you got it from. What if it stuffs up the OPs system?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NewcomerAl, thank you for the workaround. It works. I have created a GitHub repository [Handle.exe-with-Unicode-support](https://github.com/PolarGoose/Handle.exe-with-Unicode-support) from which the patched binary can be downloaded.

Comment: @PolarBear, please take a look at issues #420 and #519 in the main Sysinternals repository. There are similar patches for AccessChk.exe and DU.exe.

Comment: @NewcomerAl, thank you for pointing me to your other patches. I have incorporated them in my [Github repository](https://github.com/PolarGoose/Sysinternals-console-utils-with-Unicode-support). Please feel free to contact me via the email mentioned in my profile if you want me to change anything.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known limitation that they have no intention of fixing.
There are pages in [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/162624/handle-encoding-problem) that elude to this fact.

The suggestions on how to deal with it is to build your own copy using one of the several links provided in the link above.

You would save yourself some time looking for a solution rather than a work-around.